# Testing the results of executeBlocking

Tags: unit-testing, vert.x

I have a vertx handler code where I do an `executeBlocking` but for it to work I need to put in a `Thread.sleep()` in order for the code in the blocking code to fully execute to the point that I can check the results.

Is there a better way around this so I don't do a `Thread.sleep`?

[My handler code](https://github.com/trajano/app-ms/blob/86066526e11aa57edb2d283d3533575b5ea3cf22/ms-engine/src/main/java/net/trajano/ms/engine/SpringJaxRsHandler.java#L313) the following is the portion where I only kept the relevant components.

```
    try (final VertxHttpResponse response = new VertxHttpResponse(context)) {
        context.vertx().executeBlocking(
            future -> {
                ...
                try {
                    dispatcher.invokePropagateNotFound(request,
                        response);
                    future.complete();
                } finally {
                    ...
                }
            }, false,
            res -> {
                if (res.failed()) {
                    context.fail(wae);
                } else {
                    if (!context.response().ended()) {
                        context.response().end();
                    }
                }
            });
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
```

}

[My test](https://github.com/trajano/app-ms/blob/86066526e11aa57edb2d283d3533575b5ea3cf22/ms-engine/src/test/java/net/trajano/ms/engine/test/SpringJaxRsHandlerTest.java#L35) and the relevant parts

```
@Test
public void test(final TestContext testContext) throws Exception {

    final Router router = Router.router(rule.vertx());
    final SpringJaxRsHandler handler = SpringJaxRsHandler.registerToRouter(router, MyApp.class);
    final RoutingContext routingContext = mock(RoutingContext.class);
    when(routingContext.currentRoute()).thenReturn(router.get("/api/hello"));
    when(routingContext.vertx()).thenReturn(rule.vertx());

    final HttpServerRequest serverRequest = mock(HttpServerRequest.class);
    when(serverRequest.absoluteURI()).thenReturn("/api/hello");
    when(serverRequest.isEnded()).thenReturn(true);
    when(serverRequest.method()).thenReturn(HttpMethod.GET);
    when(routingContext.request()).thenReturn(serverRequest);

    final HttpServerResponse response = mock(HttpServerResponse.class);
    when(response.putHeader(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(response);
    when(response.headers()).thenReturn(new VertxHttpHeaders());

    when(routingContext.response()).thenReturn(response);

    handler.handle(routingContext);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    // fails without the sleep above
    verify(response, times(1)).setStatusCode(200);

}
```

I tried

```
testContext.assertTrue(routingContext.response().ended());
```

But that returned `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the code a bit so I don't use routingContext directly but the concept is still the same.  I use `Async` in combination of a `when->then(Answer)` and have the `async.complete()` be called in the `Answer`.  Once that is done do an `async.await()` to wait for the thread to finish.

```
    final Async async = testContext.async();
    when(response.write(Matchers.any(Buffer.class))).then(invocation -> {

        try {
            return response;
        } finally {
            async.complete();
        }
    });
    when(serverRequest.response()).thenReturn(response);

    router.accept(serverRequest);
    async.await();
```